# Mutli user web app login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am having trouble setting up a login that connects to specific database or table. 
I want to have a log in like this
CName:***_*__**
User:**__*_***
Password:***_*____**
where cname gives them access to their specified database.
are there any tutorials on this. I have yet to find one.
So far I have a basic database/php form set up but all users would end up submitting information to a single database instead of a personal one.
Help! If any one can point me in the right direction that would be awesome. I don't want someone doing it for me, I need to learn this though.

thanks

Comment: so, what you need is couple of if statements to check user name and set db name depending on it? if its php I think you should've added appropriate tag to question

Comment: Oh right sorry. I have just made the jump to dynamic pages and web apps. After five years of basic static pages i'm a bit overwhelmed. So basically you are saying that I can use if statements in the PHP code to point the user to the appropriate database or table. right. That makes sense.

Comment: BTW: I also assume you have a good reason for using different databases, because the usual way to categorize users would be to use usergroups in just one database

Comment: yes, my reasoning is that this app will actually hold several different clients information. I want a separate db for each client. If I am mistaken please let me know.

Comment: It is of course not wrong, depending on the amount of data that is expected, but usually one would work with one DB and if you have a 1=1 relation of user<=>client just add a column client to the user and a table clients and put the client id into the client column of the respective user, otherwise add a table clients and a lookup table assigning the user<=> client relations into the lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may add if, or switch case statement to define database depending on user name

```
switch($_REQUEST['CName']) {
    case 'user1':
        //set database to db for user1
        break;
    case 'user2':
        //set database to db for user2
        break;
    default:
        //set default database
        break;
}
```